# Entity Framework 4.1 : Linq-to-entities not compatible with sort

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am using below sorting method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(this IEnumerable<TEntity> source, string orderByProperty,
                                bool desc)
    {
        string command = desc ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";
        var type = typeof(TEntity);
        var property = type.GetProperty(orderByProperty);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
        var resultExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), command, new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType },
                                      source.AsQueryable().Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
        return source.AsQueryable().Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);
    }
```

My POCO object is like:

```
public class MyEntity
{
   .....
        [NotMapped]       
        public virtual int PropertyA
        { get { return something; } }
   .....
}
```

when performing:

```
context.MyEntities.OrderBy(sort, direction != "ASC").Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();
```

(note that sort is the name of the field I am sorting by, in this case, PropertyA.)

My problem is that OrderBy method is raising and exception saying something that the member of the type specified 'PropertyA' is not allowed in LINQ to Entities: Only are allowed initializers, entity members and navigation properties.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a `[NotMapped]` property in a database query, since the property doesn't exist in the database.

Instead, you can call `.AsEnumerable()` (before `OrderBy`) to force the query to run on the client.

Comment: I need this property to be NotMapped so I have added .AsEnumerable() before OrderBy but without success:The same error message is raised.

Comment: @user1624552: It's probably caused by your overloaded `OrderBy` and the `AsQueryable().Provider.CreateQuery...` part which turns the query into LINQ-to-Entities again. Anyway, you better think about sorting by a different property (unless the table is small) because `AsEnumerable` will cause to load the whole table into memory.

Comment: so are you saying that by doing context.MyEntities.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(sort, direction != "ASC").Skip(10).Take(10).ToList(); is loading the whole table into memory? If so, I do not want this so if I cannot change this property from NotMapped to mapped and I must sort by this field... how to do this? is it not possible?

Comment: @user1624552: No, it's not possible. But there might be an easy workaround if your "something" in `PropertyA` can be expressed by mapped properties and EF can translate this expression into SQL. For example, if "something" is just `PropertyB + PropertyC` you could use `OrderBy(x => x.PropertyB + x.PropertyC)`, etc. (not with your overloaded `OrderBy` though). Consider to ask a new question and explain what "something" is to get a possible proposal for a workaround.

Comment: @user1624552: How do you expect EF to run a query on the server using a property that doesn't exist on the server?

Comment: Ok, I understand, but although this is not mapped in database, it is mapped in the POCO object so it is possible to modify the above orderby to make it work with linq to objects taken into account asenumerable?

Comment: @user1624552: Just remove the queryable portions and `Compile()` the expression tree.

Comment: If I remove queryable from source.asqueryable.expression, and source.asqueryable.provider, then expression and provider cannot be applied to source as it is IEnumerable.Also what to do with typeof(Queryable) in the call?

Comment: @user1624552: Call `Expression.Compile()` to create a delegate, then call `.OrderBy()` or `.OrderByDescending()` directly.

Comment: @SLacks could you please post an example? also with the OrderBy method posted here I forgot to say all of you that I am gettting an error message saying that at least one object should implement IComparable. This error when the property is a navigation property and it does not know for which column of navigation property to order as navigation property points to another entity with some columns, so in this case, how to modify the method to detect if it is a navigation property and then specify the column to order by?

Comment: @user1624552: Check whether the type of the property is a class (other than `string`), and, if so, add a further expression to get some property of it.  Alternatively, make your entities implement `IComparable<T>`.